# Prove $\forall A\forall a\forall b((a\notin A\land b\notin P(A)\land|A|=|A\cup\{a\}|)\Rightarrow|P(A)|=|P(A)\cup\{b\}|)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a task I need to solve for my set theory course. I need to prove the following formula.

$\forall A \forall a \forall b ((a \notin A \land b \notin P(A) \land |A| = |A \cup \{a\}|) \Rightarrow |P(A)| = |P(A) \cup \{b\}|)$

What I am thinking is since $|A| = |A \cup \{a\}|$ is true then A should be infinite or something else that I am missing. I would appreciate some pointers that would lead to a solution. Thank you.

**Edit 1**:
Forgot to mention this should be solved in (ZF), so we dont have AC.

**Edit 2**:
So having read some other posts and comments on this, let me know if I am on the right track for the problem:

This formula mainly tells us that if $A$ is infinite then its power set $P(A)$ is infinite. So we have to prove this and I was thinking of applying Cantor's theorem for this. Another thing before that is we have to prove that $\forall A \forall a(a \notin A \land |A| = |A \cup \{a\}| \Rightarrow A$ is infinite). Which seems straight forward but I guess it is not. My attempt at it is as follows:

If $|A| = |A \cup \{a\}|$ then there is a bijection between $A$ and $A \cup \{a\}$. Assume $A$ is finite, hence $(\exists n \in \Bbb N)(|A|=n)$. But $a \notin A$ so $A \cup \{a\}$ would be finite too and would have a greater cardinality then $A$, which is a contradiction.

This seems really wrong and what worries me is that I am not using the bijection I mentioned to reach the contradiction. Some clarification would be of great help and just reminding this should all be **without** the **axiom of choice**.

Answer (score 0):

Since A is infinite, so is P(A).
Thus |P(A)| = |P(A) $\cup$ {b}|.

Exercise:  show if A is infinite, then there
is a bijection between A and A $\cup$ {a}.

To create a proof without the axiom of choice use
A is infinite iff exists bijection f:N -> A.

Comment: I took a look at [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255573/infinite-sets-a-is-infinite-iff-there-is-a-bijection-between-a-and-a-cup) and solutions that are both using the axiom of choice and I cannot use it for this problem. Can a simple proof be considering the example of the set of the natural numbers and the same set without zero. The latter is a proper subset of the former and $n \rightarrow n + 1$ is a bijection between them.

Comment: No, one example is not sufficient,  See edit.

Comment: We do not have the axiom of choice in ZF

Comment: On top of that should we not prove the other way around, since we are given that $|A| = |A \cup \{a\}|$ and we need to prove that A is infinite. Also I edited my post according to what I think.

Comment: @IvelinDinev At the bottom I gave you a hint how prove it without AxC.  To show A is infinite, show for all finite A, A is not equinumerous to A with an additional element.